# When insert from excel to sql convert all numbers to float

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Here is my code:

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into Market (Barcode,Name,Code,TemporaryStock,VatcodeID,Unit,NetValue,DiscountValue,UnderlyingValue,VatValue,TotalValue) select * from OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=" + textBox1.Text + "', 'SELECT * FROM [Page1$H:R]')", con);
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But my rows from 'N' till R are `nvarchar`, I want to convert them before insert to float. Or if there is a code for converting all `nvarchar` numbers from Excel to float

My error when I'm trying to insert into table is:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type nvarchar to float.

Should I use a case?

This is my table design:

[image]

Comment: You should bring the data in as is (extract), run your business rules to do any necessary conversions (transform), then insert into database (load). Even if it can be done in one step any bit of bad data will break the process.

Comment: Can you write me  a small example?

Comment: I can try to help if you make an attempt and have specific questions. I would probably bring the excel data into memory if its not too big as all object type then TryParse() anything not a string then insert into database. If its too big for memory use a staging table in database. These are all pretty straightforward tasks in themselves and very googleable.

Comment: Also it was be very usefull if i was convert specific excel rows before insert. But i dont know if it is possible.Something like this insert into sql_table select Cast(N1 as float), Cast(O1 as float), Cast(P1 as float) from  OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'....

Comment: It could work but as soon as something cannot be casted it breaks. If your data is always 100% clean you are lucky.

Comment: Where should i place my insert Row and with what form? Select Cast N,O,L from OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=" + textBox1.Text + "', 'SELECT * FROM [Page1$H:R]') or  Select * from OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=" + textBox1.Text + "', 'SELECT Cast(N,O,L) FROM [Page1$H:R]') None of them didnt worked till now

Comment: Sorry, I never use oledb to query excel  , I use the ClosedXML library so I really am not the person to instruct on that.

Comment: I find that when working with Excel data it can be easier to use Access as an intermediary step between Excel and SQL Server, since Office applications "play nice" together and you can use table links between Access and SQL Server. And as Crowcoder says, importing the data "as is" and then cleaning it before it gets to the SQL database is a good idea, and something you can do in Access. Or just give up writing your own ETL code and use SSIS :)